# How to redirect all visitors but search engine bots using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to permanently redirect all visitors to an specific domain except search bots (Google, Yahoo, MSN, etc.), How should I do it using htaccess?

Comment: Search for http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[.htaccess]+bot or http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mod-rewrite]+bot and you will find some answers, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/18076099/1741542, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12904684/1741542

Comment: @OlafDietsche: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904684/htaccess-301-redirection-for-the-bots ... but I don't know how to edit rules to match my case. I think that is vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the rules using negation in `RewriteCond` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(110\.174\.129\.147|203\.217\.17\.162)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(Googlebot|msnbot|Surp) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you please tell me how to do it with IP addresses? I mean I need to allow some websites just like the search bots and don't redirect them. How can I allow IP or Domain?

Comment: Thank you very much. Just another question. Can I join the first part of conditions with OR ? I mean something like this: %{HTTP_CLIENT_IP|REMOTE_ADDR|...}

Comment: No that cannot be done, better be separate conditions.

Answer (score 0):

To allow all bots, you can implement a do nothing rule, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (bot|spider) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

This rule triggers for all visitors, which have either `bot` or `spider` in their user agent string. You can be more specific of course, if you want only a few bots like Google, Yahoo and Bing. When the condition is met, nothing else happens.

To redirect everybody else to another domain, just append a simple redirect rule

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com [R,L]
```

When everything works as you expect, you can change `R` to `R=301`.
Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.