# How to redirect only spider bot to another site

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like visitors to continue see a domain (www.example.com) but searchengines have to redirect to the new site (www.newsite.com).

I need this redirect only for the homepage. I know I can achieve this with a rel canonical but if I'd want to insert something in htaccess how can I do this?

In [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088045/how-to-redirect-all-visitors-but-search-engine-bots-using-htaccess/27245645#27245645) i see something similar (the opposite of what i need), but I dont'know how to ajust it so it suits my needs.

this is my htaccess (where i can put the code lines?)

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName example.it

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Insert filters
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml

# Drop problematic browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the answer in the purposed helpful link, remove the exclamation marks `!`:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(110\.174\.129\.147|203\.217\.17\.162)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Googlebot|msnbot|Surp) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

So in your .htaccess example, change this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

To this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(110\.174\.129\.147|203\.217\.17\.162)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Googlebot|msnbot|Surp) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thank you @RichardBernards 
....this is my htacces....(where have i insert the lines above?)

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName example.it

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# END WordPress

Comment: thanks for your help ...i did the change....but in google webmastertolls when i go to scan > see how Google... it show sme the old domain no a redirect status...

Comment: have i to change the code numer 110\.174 etc etc with other number?...i don't know what these number mean

Comment: @luigi I don't know exactly how webmastertools scans your page, so sadly no help there. The numbers are parts of ip-addresses which are used by searchengines to crawl. It could be the webmastertools use a different ip for scanning your page than the actual Googlebot does...

Answer (score 1):

ok thanks to @RichardBernards.....it works great...i deleted the line code

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(110\.174\.129\.147|203\.217\.17\.162)
```

and now it is ok.....thank you very much