# HtAccess Redirect, if Google/MSN bot and only for a url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i want to redirect only if it is a google bot or MSN bot.
and only if the url is `http://myblog.com/post.html`

then i want to make 301 redirect to `http://googlebot.com/trolled.htm`

**PS: I WANT TO MAKE THE REDIRECT USING HTACCESS**

**in code language**

```
//code is worng but to make you understand my question
if(googlebot OR msn)
{
   if url(http://myblog.com/post.html){
            redirect (`http://googlebot.com/trolled.htm)
   }
}
```

**HTACCESS CODE I TRIED**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myblog.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} msnbot
RewriteRule http://myblog.com/post.html http://googlebot.com/trolled.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: see here [redirect google bot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904684/htaccess-301-redirection-for-the-bots)

Comment: @Fred-ii- That is not exact duplicate since OP know how to use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` here.

Comment: @anubhava If you say so.

Answer (score 1):

You can only match URI in `RewriteRule` without protocol and host name part.

Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myblog\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (msnbot|Googlebot) [NC]
RewriteRule ^post\.html$ http://googlebot.com/trolled.html [L,R=301]
```